# React: Chrome browser hangs on localhost (error code 5)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

Am new to React and my first app opened fine in browser, but now when I do npm start the Chrome on Mac browser hangs and returns error code 5. Cleared cache and extensions but problem persists and all other apps beside VS Code. No error message in Terminal.

Here is my code in slightly condensed form; I left the array data out:

```
import React from "react"
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client"

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <Menu />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  )
}

function Header() {
  return <h1>Fast React Pizza Co.</h1>
}

function Menu() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Our menu</h2>
      <Pizza />
      <Pizza />
      <Pizza />
      <Pizza />
    </div>
  )
}

function Footer() {
  return (
    <Footer>{new Date().toLocaleTimeString()} "We're currently open!"</Footer>
  )
}

function Pizza() {
  return (
    <div>
      <img src="pizzas/spinaci.jpg" alt="Pizza Spinaci" />
      <h2>Pizza Spinaci</h2>
      <p>Tomato, mozarella, spinach, and ricotta cheese</p>
    </div>
  )
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"))
root.render(<App />)
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "pizza-menu",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Terminal message:

Compiled successfully!

You can now view pizza-menu in the browser.

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://10.72.172.175:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.

webpack compiled successfully

Comment: Hi!  Do you have more context to your environment?  Maybe the package.json script for the start command?

Comment: Hi, I have added the contents of package.json and the Terminal message. Thank you.